# How to have a master detail datatableview in django using MultipleDatatableView

Tags: django, master-detail, datatables-1.10

I'd like to have a master-detail datatableview in my app.
I've used MultipleDatatableView according to [the document](https://github.com/pivotal-energy-solutions/django-datatable-view/blob/master/demo_app/example_app/views.py#L1124).

I'm confused How to edit the front and add a GET parameter hint (exp: ?datatable=master) . Without using MultipleDatatableView, my code works correctly but when I change it to multiple, it doen't work because of this error:

> django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'datatable'

I tried to add  datatable=master in the option of datatable, but this doesn't work.